# Foundcell that is not empty in the column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to only display a combo box list that is not empty but it's not working. Why? Though I add this line "If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then"

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

    If SearchTeamComboBox.ListIndex < 0 And SearchSelectPPComboBox.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select Team and the Process/project you want to search ."
        SearchTeamComboBox.SetFocus
    ElseIf SearchTeamComboBox.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select Team."
        SearchTeamComboBox.SetFocus
    ElseIf SearchSelectPPComboBox.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Process/project you want to search ."
        SearchSelectPPComboBox.SetFocus
    Else
        Dim WHAT_TO_FIND As String
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

        WHAT_TO_FIND = SearchSelectPPComboBox.Value
        Set ws = Sheets(SearchTeamComboBox.Value)
        Set FoundCell = ws.Range("F8:F" & ws.Range("F8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Find(what:=WHAT_TO_FIND, lookat:=xlWhole)
        'If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " is found ")
            Me.ExistingProcessProjectNameTextbox = FoundCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
            Me.ExistingTeamComboBox = SearchTeamComboBox.Value
            Me.ExistingchecklistComboBox.Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Me.ExistingORRComboBox.Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Me.ExistingdateTextBox.Value = FoundCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        End If
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Next codes! ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
 Private Sub SearchTeamComboBox_Change()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    SearchSelectPPComboBox.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim PP As Object
Dim rngList As Range
Dim strSelected As String
Dim LastRow As Long
        ' check that a team has been selected
      If SearchTeamComboBox.ListIndex <> -1 Then

           strSelected = SearchTeamComboBox.Value

                If strSelected = "ACLT" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("ACLT").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("ACLT").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "AIFCIF" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("AIFCIF").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("AIFCIF").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "FDM" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("FDM").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("FDM").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "Imaging" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("Imaging").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("Imaging").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "MRT" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("MRT").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("MRT").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "PAT" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("PAT").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("PAT").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "SSU" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("SSU").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("SSU").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

                ElseIf strSelected = "VEL" Then
                LastRow = Worksheets("VEL").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngList = Worksheets("VEL").Range("E8:E" & LastRow)

            End If

                For Each PP In rngList
                If Len(PP.Value) > 0 Then
                SearchSelectPPComboBox.AddItem PP.Offset(, 1)

            Next PP
        End If

        End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I added conditions for each combo box to add items only if not empty, in the Else branch

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

    Dim cmbTeam As ComboBox, cmbPP As ComboBox, lastRow As Long
    Dim searchedText As String, ws As Worksheet, found As Range

    Set cmbTeam = SearchTeamComboBox
    Set cmbPP = SearchSelectPPComboBox

    If cmbTeam.ListIndex < 0 And cmbPP.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select Team and the Process/project to search."
        cmbTeam.SetFocus
    ElseIf cmbTeam.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select Team."
        cmbTeam.SetFocus
    ElseIf cmbPP.ListIndex < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Process/project to search."
        cmbPP.SetFocus
    Else
        searchedText = cmbPP.Value
        Set ws = Worksheets(cmbTeam.Value)
        lastRow = ws.Range("F8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Set found = ws.Range("F8:F" & lastRow).Find(what:=searchedText, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            With found
                MsgBox (searchedText & " is found ")
                If Len(.Offset(0, 0).Value) > 0 Then Me.ExistingProcessProjectNameTextbox = .Offset(0, 0).Value
                Me.ExistingTeamComboBox = cmbTeam.Value
                If Len(.Offset(0, 1).Value) > 0 Then Me.ExistingchecklistComboBox.Value = .Offset(0, 1).Value
                If Len(.Offset(0, 2).Value) > 0 Then Me.ExistingORRComboBox.Value = .Offset(0, 2).Value
                If Len(.Offset(0, 3).Value) > 0 Then Me.ExistingdateTextBox.Value = .Offset(0, 3).Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I also removed one extra "End If", but I didn't test it (don't have your form)

---

**Edit:**

You can fix the For Each part by replacing this:

```
For Each PP In rngList
If Len(PP.Value) > 0 Then
SearchSelectPPComboBox.AddItem PP.Offset(, 1)
Next PP
```

with this

```
For Each PP In rngList
    If Len(PP.Offset(, 1)) > 0 Then SearchSelectPPComboBox.AddItem PP.Offset(, 1).Value2
Next
```

or this

```
For Each PP In rngList
    If Len(PP.Offset(, 1).Value2) > 0 Then
        SearchSelectPPComboBox.AddItem PP.Offset(, 1).Value2
    End If
Next
```

It's also safe to change `Dim PP As Object` to `Dim PP As Range`

Comment: It worked! How about the combobox list? How can I list only the not empty cells. I tried adding " If Len(PP.Value) > 0" behind "For Each PP In rngList" but they showed "Compile error: Next without for"... I added this new codes in the question, under "Next codes!" @paulbica

Comment: It worked! THANK YOU! Btw last question, how do you make the enter key work instead of clicking on the command button. By setting default from 'false to true', don't work for me as I have two command button on the userform. :( @paulbica

Comment: What object will have the focus when the enter key is pressed?